# React: Apollo Client: Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to make a component that wraps Apollo Client's Query component. I am using `apollo-link-state` for local state management and I want to have an error notification system that notifies the user of all the things.

my component looks like this...

```
export class Viewer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <Query query={GET_VIEWER}>
        {({ data, client, error }) => {
          if (error) {
            client.mutate({
              mutation: ADD_NOTIFICATION,
              variables: { message: unpackApolloErr(error), type: 'Error' }
            });
          }

          return children(data.viewer ? data.viewer : user);
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}
```

but when it tries to add the error with the mutation, I get the react error..

```
Warning: forceUpdate(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

I don't see an obvious way around this and I don't see why it is even happening if the client is provided as a render prop and cannot be used...I must be missing something simple but I cant see what it is

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#network to try to update the client when there's an error? That way you don't need to wrap Apollo's Query component and you can just add a link

Comment: I wanted to use that, but since it is declared before the client is declared, I couldn't find a way to include mutations to the local state through the `onError` function

Comment: Why not declare the client outside the scope of where you initialize the client? and onError (if (client) client.mutate))

Comment: I will try that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @KennethTruong I don't think I can call the apolli client constructor without the error link... which needs to be decalred first. Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this work? let client; const errorLink = <your code here that accesses the client>;  client = new ApolloClient({ links }); <ApolloProvider client={client}>. Sorry its hard to format the code in the comment

Comment: I logged `this` from within the `onError` function and it turns out that `this.client` is available by default...

Comment: Cool! Let me know if it works for you (:

Comment: Btw if my comments helped you. can you accept my answer? I'm trying to build in Rep :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that the client is available in the `onError` function as `this` when using `apollo-link-error` https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error.html

I had tried to use `onError` before to access the client, but it was not obvious that the scope which it is called in does indeed contain the client even if the client is declared after the `onError` handler

```
// client is available here even though it is defined first 
const err = onError({ graphQLErrors }) => {
    this.client.mutate({ mutation: ADD_ERROR, variables: { graphQLErrors }})
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link: ApolloLink.from([err, httpLink])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there was a `Warning: forceUpdate` was probably because Apollo internally will cause a forceUpdate when there is a mutation. So mutations should be in the `render` method.

The best way to handle mutations after an Apollo error is to add an onError link as described in https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#network

```
// Add errorLink into Apollo Client
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  this.client.mutate({ mutation: ..., variables: {}});
});


const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([err, httpLink])
})
```